# How can I remove the section "Last modified" from an embeded Google drive folder?

Tags: iframe, google-drive-api, embed

I am trying to embed a Google drive folder in a wordpress site, but I only need it to display the document title. Currently it shows both, the title and the date last modified.

I am using this code:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=MY_FOLDERS_ID#list" style="width:100%; height:250px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

and as a result I get this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUvvo.png)

The thing is that the "Last modified" column hides parts of the title and I really need the full titles to be displayed.

I've been searching for something that would improve this, but I could not find any solutions.

Comment: Tell us _what_ you searched for instead of just telling us you searched.